# How to add chat sound notifications?

Tags: flash, audio, notifications, chat

Hey, I have developed a chat site and would like to add a sound notification (beep or something) when there is a new message kind of like facebook chat.

I know this requires flash but have no idea on how this could be accomplished. Can anybody explain how to make this or a good resource that explains it?

Comment: This does not require Flash and all normal browsers understand the HTML5 audio-tag. IE is not a normal browser, but luckily it's not the most-used browser in Europe anymore :D

Comment: ok, html5 sounds good, but any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). "*By wrapping and extending HTML5 and Flash Audio APIs, SoundManager 2 brings reliable cross-platform audio to JavaScript.*"

I don't want to rain on the HTML5 parade, but as I understand it, the audio tag currently has about 50% market reach (according to http://caniuse.com/#search=audio) and there is an issue regarding formats, Firefox doesn't support MP3, so I would recommend letting SoundManager 2 take care of such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Forget using Flash for this. Use either HTML5 (http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp), or the old fashioned way (http://www.world-voices.com/resources/addaud.html#350).

Best of luck.